# Sending a diagnostic file from a C# utility

Tags: c#, email-attachments

I have a utility written in C# that will collect a bunch of things needed for diagnosing an issue with a piece of software (some env variables, versions of the software installed, various log and config files from it, etc...) and wrap them all up in a zip.  I'd like to make this as easy as possible for the end user to send me this file.  Ideally, I'd like an email to come up in their default mail client, with a pre-set to: field, subject line, etc... and the file attached.  They could then make any modifications they wanted, or just hit send.  Running into the following issues:

1. I can't use mailto, since I need an attachment and that's not supported.
2. I know that a number of the end users do not use Outlook, so I can't code specifically for that (or anything, for that matter).
3. I don't know anything about the end users' mail systems/credentials, etc... so I can't send the email directly through SMTP.  I don't want to just code in a gmail account or something because I don't want it to break if we had to change a password or something.  Also, the email should come from the end user.
4. From what I can see, MAPI is unsupported in .NET.  I found some code that supposedly makes it work anyway, but I've also seen that it can cause memory leaks, etc...  Also, does that work well with all non-Outlook mail clients?

Are there any options I'm missing here?  Thanks!

ETA:  Sorry, should have added - we've considered using FTP and it's an option, but far from ideal, since it means additional steps on our end (we've got workflows around emails).

Comment: Have you considered FTP?

Comment: Considered, but hoping not to.  See comment below.

Comment: I don't have any experience with it, but elsewhere I got a suggestion to use uuencoding.  1. it seems to have been mostly replaced with base64 as far as I can tell? and 2. I'm not sure how it would help the situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bill said in his comment, using FTP is probably your best bet. 
You can use the `FTPWebRequest` class:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

// Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

response.Close();
```

Code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx

Comment: I thought about that.  Was hoping to find an alternative because 1. it means allowing anonymous FTP, and 2. then we have more steps on our end (when an email comes in with an attachment, it's all just stored in CRM under the user's account, whereas if it's FTP'd then we have to go get it, and then attach it manually, etc...unless I can find some way to script that too).  So it's an option, but definitely not preferred if there's anyway to deal with email instead.  Thanks for the sample code, though - will definitely be a nice start if we do have to go this way.

Comment: @teleute00 I wouldn't think there's anything wrong with Anon FTP as long as it's properly controlled. I don't think there's any easy way to achieve what you're looking at with email given your circumstance. Your other option would be a web service it would automatically post to...but that would likely be more work than setting up FTP.

Comment: I don't actually have the power to authorize an anon FTP on our end, though, and if past experience is a guide I'll have a heck of a time convincing TPTB.  But if it's the only option...:-(

Comment: @teleute00 It wouldn't have to be anonymous. You could always add the credentials into the program - which of course would be a pain to manage if you wanted to change them. But it would be entirely possible to do.

Comment: Yeah - that future maintenance thing is a kicker, since you don't really have control over the end user's system once they've installed...

Comment: So we're going with the web service, since we've already got some of the tools in place for that anyway.  Not the answer I wanted, but maybe the answer I deserved.  ;-)  Thanks!

Comment: @teleute00 No problem. A web service may end up being even better!